# What are the names of these tools and what are they used for?

Tags: tools

Found these in my Dad's collection.  Any ideas of what they are called and what they were used for?  The top tool is 11 3/4" and the bottom one (with one end like a flat screwdriver) is 6".

[image]

Comment: Without a scale to tell the size I would offer 2 possibilities, o ring removal tools possibly a spring hook. But would lean to o ring removal.

Comment: FYI the next time you post a tool like that for identification it helps to put something next to it to indicate some kind of scale. A coin or a ruler for example

Comment: That top one looks like dental tool, no?  Oh, you know what?  Leather tools is my bet.

Comment: The top tool could be used to remove "packing" from the packing gland of a shaft seal. Of course there could be many other uses.

Answer (score 3):

A reasonable guess would be cotter pin extractors. Here's a picture of [similar tool from Snapon.](https://store.snapon.com/Cotter-Pin-Pullers-Cotter-Pin-Puller-10-long-P636021.aspx) The bottom one looks vaguely like a different style with one pointed end to pull and a flat one to spread the pins.

[image]